# RPI4 Model B won't boot Kali Linux, TV shows “No Signal” or Rainbow screen

Tags: boot, pi-4, hdmi, screen, kali

I have RPI4 model B and I've installed `Kali Linux Kali Linux RaspberryPi 2, 3 and 4` on my SDcard 64gb through Balena Etcher but when powered on, my LG tv shows "no signal", HDMI is well connected.

I tried in config.txt:

- hdmi_force_hotplug=1   -> "no signal screen"
- hdmi_safe=1  -> "rainbow color splash screen"

Could you please help me ?

https://images.offensive-security.com/arm-images/kali-linux-2020.2b-rpi3-nexmon.img.xz

Comment: does the pi work with raspberry pi OS?

Comment: yes it has been working with Raspbian for months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- check HDMI cable
- set `hdmi_safe=1`
- try set parameters `hdmi_group` and `hdmi_mode` for your display (watch next point)
- read [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md)

Comment: Thank for help, it did not work, I tried that already. :( 
But I formated the SDcard again, and connected it to my laptop with USB-SDcard adaptor this time (was SDcard adaptor before).
Tried only hdmi_safe=1 option,  and 1sec after rainbow it has booted.
But at the end I have black screen blinking with the mouse. There is nothing I can do. This is a nightmare :)

Comment: `hdmi_safe` includes `hdmi_force_hotplug` (ie., enabling them both is harmless but redundant): https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

Comment: @WBRPI4 then the problem is most likely in drivers or the graphics environment cannot boot for any other reasons

Comment: @goldilocks indeed, did not notice when reading the documentation